# 8bit old school nintendo sound FX

Tags: game, sound-effects

Does anyone know where to buy these things in library form legally?

Answer (score 5):

It would be better to create them by yourself. Download FamiTracker, spend about 2-3 hours on reading the tutorial and studying examples, then voila - you get a handful of NES sounds. :)

Also pay some attention to the YMvst plugin.

Answer (score 4):

Chipsounds is fantastic and very user friendly. You can create some very authentic sounds using the presets.

http://www.plogue.com/products/chipsounds/

Answer (score 4):

http://www.drpetter.se/project_sfxr.html

sfxr is a wonderful tool. It was created in 2007 for use in game jams where the creators didn't have time to worry about searching for sounds. It's highly tweakable, but at its core, in my opinion, is the "randomize" button. After a few clicks, you are bound to land on an interesting new sound that fits your needs. It even has categorized generators to randomly generate anything from pickup/coin sounds to explosions to hits. And it all has that 8bit sound.

EDIT: I forgot to mention that it also has a "mutate" button to slightly, but again randomly, alter the sound.

Comment: Also love SFXR. Great recommendation if you're strapped for time, even though I think learning FamiTracker might provide better results in the end.

Comment: I agree with Miles. Used cfxr(mac version of sfxr) in a MOW recently, worked great.  Was able to quickly create a bunch of fx, save to a folder, and then just drag and drop them into Protools.

Answer (score 1):

Puremagnetik has a super budget option ($12), for Logic, Live or Kontakt. [Punchpak](http://puremagnetik.com/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=85&Itemid=50)

Answer (score 0):

If you've got a bit more cash to spend, I seriously advise looking into getting the [reFX Nexus 2](http://refx.com/products/nexus/summary/) plugin with the SID expansion.

If you like making electronic music then the Nexus 2 is an amazing plugin to have generally, and well worth the money.

[Have a listen here for a demo of the SID extension.](http://cdn.refxstatic.com/mp3/nexus/exp_SID.mp3)

Answer (score 0):

[**Cosmic boys - icecream VST**](http://www.kvraudio.com/product/icecream_by_cosmic_boys)

8-bit, Chip-style, Mono/Poly synthesizer.

**Features:**

```
Dual Oscillators.
4 Octave per OSC.
Osc2 Fine tune.
Step Sequencer Pitch/Filter.
Bitcrusher 8-bit, 16-bit, 24-bit, 32-bit.
Filter Section.
Amp/Filter ADSR.
Harmonics Switch.
Reverb/Delay.
X/Y Pad.
Glide and Glide Rate.
```