# Retro handheld game sound

Tags: vintage, handheld, game

How to make a real retro handheld game sound?
Any software?

[Retro Handheld Video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vtunnYlN1zQ)

Answer (score 2):

Do some research on 8-bit/chiptune.  This previous question should be a good starting point: [Native Instruments 8-bit Chiptune](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/14753/native-instruments-8-bit-chiptune/14793#14793)